# Uploading an image file using axios in laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3, axios

I am new to axios so i need help. I am uploading an image file using axios in laravel 5.3 but axios is not passing the image file to the server. here is my axios code.

```
formSubmit: function(){

        axios.post('/postdata',this.$data,)
            .then(response => alert('Success'))
            .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data));

    },
```

the entire form data is submitted except the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should use `FormData()` object when dealing with ajax file upload.

```
let formData = new FormData();
this.form.append(ele.target.name, files[0])

axios.post('/postdata', formData)
        .then(response => alert('Success'))
        .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data));
```